# locators in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 500px; top: 156px; left: 706px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-comment-dialog">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div id="comment-dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="background-color: white; width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 208.267px;">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1002;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1003;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1004;"></div>
            <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
                <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">Edit Approved Data</span>
                    </button>

                    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
```

i want to locate the "Edit Approved Data" button  but gets an error always saying element not found.

Comment: i have tried xpath for the button  and i am new to this so not sure how to use cssselector for this.

Comment: can you list what all xpaths have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button`

`//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[1]`

`//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button/span`

`//span[text()='Edit Approved Data']`

`//\*[text()='Edit Approved Data']`

The way to use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
```

Every presented **xpath** should work